# Mobile compatiblity while generating web pages

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, mobile

HI,

I am writing a web application which has a portal page that should work properly in desktop browser and mobile devices. When i write the html/css/javascript/jsp content, i want to make sure this code works properly in both desktop browsers and mobile browsers. I can test desktop browser functionality with the development server itself.

To make sure it works well with mobile also, is there any simulator where in if i paste my code, i can see the output in that simulated mobile browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the quickest and easiest ways to ensure existing web pages display well on mobile platforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100519/what-are-the-quickest-and-easiest-ways-to-ensure-existing-web-pages-display-well)

Comment: [Look this great list](http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators).

Answer (score 1):

iPhone: http://www.testiphone.com/

Opera Mini: http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/

And here is a list of other useful resources: http://mobiforge.com/emulators/page/mobile-emulators